# How to extract unique levels from 2 columns in a data frame in r

Tags: r, unique, dataframe

I have the data.frame

```
df<-data.frame("Site.1" = c("A", "B", "C"),
               "Site.2" = c("D", "B", "B"),
               "Tsim" = c(2, 4, 7), 
               "Jaccard" = c(5, 7, 1))

#    Site.1 Site.2 Tsim Jaccard
#  1      A      D    2       5
#  2      B      B    4       7
#  3      C      B    7       1
```

I can get the unique levels for each column using

```
top.x<-unique(df[1:2,c("Site.1")])
top.x

# [1] A B
# Levels: A B C

top.y<-unique(df[1:2,c("Site.2")])
top.y

# [1] D B
# Levels: B D
```

How do I get the unique levels for both columns and turn them into a vector i.e:

```
v <- c("A", "B", "D")
v
# [1] "A" "B" "D"
```

Comment: +1 for providing sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
top.xy <- unique(unlist(df[1:2,]))
top.xy

[1] A B D
Levels: A B C D
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately it didn't work as I have additional numeric columns as well. I updated my question to reflect this. Sorry about that. Any ideas on the updated data.frame? Cheers.

Comment: Well, select the relevant columns: `top.xy <- unique(unlist(df[1:2,c("Site.1","Site.2")]))`

Comment: @Elizabeth, specifying the columns with something like `as.vector(unique(unlist(df[1:2, 1:2])))` works.

Comment: Thanks to both of you I used a combination of your answers to solve the problem. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Try `union`:

```
union(top.x, top.y)
# [1] "A" "B" "D"
union(unique(df[1:2, c("Site.1")]), 
      unique(df[1:2, c("Site.2")]))
# [1] "A" "B" "D"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unique levels for the firs two collumns:

```
de<- apply(df[,1:2],2,unique)  
de

# $Site.1  
# [1] "A" "B" "C"  

# $Site.2  
# [1] "D" "B"
```

Then you can take the symmetric difference of the two sets:

```
union(setdiff(de$Site.1,de$Site.2), setdiff(de$Site.2,de$Site.1))  
# [1] "A" "C" "D"
```

If you're intrested in just two first two rows (as in your example):

```
de<- apply(df[1:2,1:2],2,unique)  
de  
#      Site.1 Site.2  
# [1,] "A"    "D"   
# [2,] "B"    "B"  
union(de[,1],de[,2])  
# [1] "A" "B" "D"
```